# Logic issue in array indexing

Tags: ios, nsarray

I've probably been starting at this too long and simply can't see the logic problem. I'm changing background images on a pan gesture. Swiping left/right cycles thru an array of image names for the background and loops.

Swiping Right (increasing) works fine, it loops back to the start of my array.
Swiping Left (decreasing stops at the first object in my array (objectIndex: 0).

```
NSLog(@"_imageBackgroundIndex Before:%d",_imageBackgroundIndex);

if ([_panDirection isEqual:@"Right"]) 
{ 
    _imageBackgroundIndex = _imageBackgroundIndex + 1;
}

if ([_panDirection isEqual:@"Left"]) 
{ 
    _imageBackgroundIndex = _imageBackgroundIndex - 1;
}


NSLog(@"_imageBackgroundIndex After:%d",_imageBackgroundIndex);

if (_imageBackgroundIndex > ([_backgroundImages count] - 1)) 
{ 
    _imageBackgroundIndex = 0;
}

if (_imageBackgroundIndex < 0) 
{ 
    _imageBackgroundIndex = ([_backgroundImages count] - 1);
}


[[self childNodeWithName:kBackgroundName] runAction:
    [SKAction setTexture:
        [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:
            [_backgroundImages objectAtIndex:_imageBackgroundIndex]]]];
```

Anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay (though there are some style improvements to consider once you get it working).  I'd wager that you have `_imageBackgroundIndex` declared as an `unsigned int` or `NSUInteger`.  When you think it drops below zero, it's really taking on a huge unsigned value.

This code will work (and has better style) even if the counter is declared unsigned...

```
- (void)incrementIndex {
    BOOL increment = self.imageBackgroundIndex < self.backgroundImages.count-1;
    self.imageBackgroundIndex = (increment)? self.imageBackgroundIndex+1 : 0;
}

- (void)decrementIndex {
    BOOL decrement = self.imageBackgroundIndex > 0;
    self.imageBackgroundIndex = (decrement)? self.imageBackgroundIndex-1 : self.backgroundImages.count-1;
}
```

Then your pan method becomes simpler:

```
// not sure how panDirection is initialized, is it really a string @"Left" or @"Right"?
// if so, use isEqualToString to compare strings

if ([_panDirection isEqualToString:@"Right"]) [self incrementIndex];
else if ([_panDirection isEqualToString:@"Left"]) [self decrementIndex];

[[self childNodeWithName:kBackgroundName] runAction:// ... etc
```